# UIImagePickerController, saveing 2 images to documentsdir with different names

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios7, uiimagepickercontroller

i would like to save 2 images as they get picked to separate names.

i used this guide to make my uiimagepickercontroller : [guide](https://teamtreehouse.com/forum/showing-two-images-in-one-viewcontroller-picked-with-uiimagepickercontroller-from-different-buttons)

basically it's one uiimagepickercontroller that manages 2 uiimageviews, is it possible to make it save 2 different images with separate names ? or should i try to make uiimagepickercontroller different ?

here's my code, and it not's working for saving.

```
- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info {

NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *imagePath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"latest_photo.png"];

//extracting image from the picker and saving it
NSString *mediaType = [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerMediaType];
if ([mediaType isEqualToString:@"public.image"]){
    UIImage *editedImage = [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerEditedImage];
    NSData *webData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(editedImage);
    [webData writeToFile:imagePath atomically:YES];
}
switch (_selectedPhotoType) {
    case imageView1Type:
        imageView1.image = [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage];
        break;
    case imageView2Type:
        imageView2.image = [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage];
        break;
    default:
        break;
}

[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:^{ }];
}
```

Comment: so you want to save the same picked image to 2 different files?

Comment: simple question do u want one button with two selectors or two button with one selector.....

Comment: @heximal no, i have 2 uiimageviews, when i click the button under each of them, i select 2 different images... i want to save them under each in depending names

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this implementation. Is that you need?

```
- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info {

        NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
        NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
        NSString *imagePath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"latest_photo.png"];

        //extracting image from the picker and saving it
        NSString *mediaType = [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerMediaType];
        UIImage *editedImage = [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerEditedImage];
        NSData *webData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(editedImage);
        NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
        NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
        switch (_selectedPhotoType) {
            case imageView1Type: {
                NSString *imagePath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"latest_photo1.png"];
                imageView1.image = [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage];
        }
                break;
            case imageView2Type: {
                NSString *imagePath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"latest_photo2.png"];
                imageView2.image = [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage];
        }
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
        [webData writeToFile:imagePath atomically:YES];

        [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:^{ }];
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

figured it out with little help from @Heximal

```
- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info {

NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *imagePath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"latest_photo.png"];

//extracting image from the picker and saving it
    NSString *mediaType = [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerMediaType];
switch (_selectedPhotoType) {
    case imageView1Type: {
        NSString *imagePath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"latest_photo1.png"];
        imageView1.image = [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerEditedImage];
        if ([mediaType isEqualToString:@"public.image"]){
            UIImage *editedImage = [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerEditedImage];
            NSData *webData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(editedImage);
            [webData writeToFile:imagePath atomically:YES];
        }

    }
        break;
    case imageView2Type: {
        NSString *imagePath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"latest_photo2.png"];
        imageView2.image = [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerEditedImage];
        if ([mediaType isEqualToString:@"public.image"]){
            UIImage *editedImage = [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerEditedImage];
            NSData *webData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(editedImage);
            [webData writeToFile:imagePath atomically:YES];
        }
    }
        break;
    default:
        break;
}

[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:^{ }];
}
```